# Is it possible to hide either of the 2 bars in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to hide either of the 2 bars?

[image]

I am running Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) on macOS 10.13.6 (17G65).

Comment: You mean kiosk mode?

Comment: Press F11, or run Chrome in kiosk mode.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Yes, that would be an option.